# Обособление распространенного определения в препозиции к определяемому существительному

Tags: пунктуация

Нужно ли обособлять следующее распространенное определение?

В ближайшей перспективе планируется запуск эксклюзивной, спроектированной специально под продукцию компании (,) автоматической линии по производству фланцев и заглушек.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нет, конечно. Первая запятая разделяет однородные члены, а вторая не нужна.

Comment: Спасибо большое.